# Install twitter bootstrap theme into rails 4 app - Vendor/assets directory not found?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to install a theme from `wrapbootstrap.com` into my rails 4.1 application.

I created a new app with rails 4 scaffolding. I then took the downloaded zip directory which includes 4 directories and an index.html file and placed them where I thought they should go:

`css` moved to `vendor/assets/stylesheets`, `js` moved to `vendor/assets/javascripts`, `font` moved to `vendor/assets/fonts`, and `img` moved to `vendor/assets/images`.

I then added this code to me `app/assets/stylesheets` file:

`*= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/.`

and this code to my `app/assets/javascripts` file:

`//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.`

At this point, I assumed I had all the files I needed in place, so I copied `index.html` over into my app and pointed my browser to the appropriate view. Basically all I see is plain text - The css/javascript/image files are not working as intended.

When looking at my google Chrome developer tools, I see a bunch of errors similar to this one:

`GET http://localhost:3000/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css 404 (Not Found)`

What am I missing here to get this theme to work?

## EDIT:

my html file looks like this where I am requiring the files:

```
<!-- Styles -->
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Font awesome CSS -->
        <link href="../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Pretty Photo -->
        <link href="../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Animate -->
        <link href="../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: try running production env.. just to generate the minified assets... then try running the development once again... worked with me before.

Comment: Dont put vendor path in the href just add normal ` <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>` and include other css in application.css file
`

Comment: @jbmyid That did it. Thanks man, feel free to post an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont put vendor path in the href just add normal 
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>` and include other css in application.css file`